# How to reuse the same UIButton in multiple views

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've created a button like so:

```
UIButton *toTop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
toTop.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 37, 38);
toTop.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[toTop setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toTop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[toTop addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I have various UIViews that I would like to use this same button over and over again on, but I can't do it. I've tried adding the same `UIButton` to multiple views but it always just appears on the last place I added it. I've also tried:

```
UIButton *toTop2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
toTop2 = toTop;
```

which doesn't work. Is there an efficient way to do this without setting all the same properties for this same button over and over? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`s can only ever have a single superview. With the second approach, you are simply allocating a button, then throwing it away and assigning its pointer to point to the first button. So now `toTop` and `toTop2` both point to the exact same button instance and you are back to the single superview limitation.

So, you'll need to create separate `UIButton` instances to accomplish this. One way to do this without duplicating code is to write a category. Something like this should work:

UIButton+ToTopAdditions.h:

```
@interface UIButton (ToTopAdditions)

+ (UIButton *)toTopButtonWithTarget:(id)target;

@end
```

UIButton+ToTopAdditions.m:

```
@implementation UIButton (ToTopAdditions)

+ (UIButton *)toTopButtonWithTarget:(id)target
{
    UIButton *toTop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    toTop.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 37, 38);
    toTop.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [toTop setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toTop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [toTop addTarget:target action:@selector(scrollToTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return toTop;
}

@end
```

Import `UIButton+ToTopAdditions.h`, pass the appropriate target to the method (sounds like that would be `self` in your case), and you'll get as many identical buttons as you need. Hope this helps!